# How to calculate this derivative? Do I have to use the chain rule?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Derivative of $(r^2 - x^2)^{1/2}$ with respect to x? Please show the steps also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For solving using the chain rule**
$$\frac{d(r^2-x^2)^{1/2}}{dx}=\frac{d(r^2-x^2)^{1/2}}{d(r^2-x^2)}.\frac{d(r^2-x^2)}{dx}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(r^2-x^2)^{-1/2}.(\frac{d(r^2)}{dx}-\frac{d(x^2)}{dx})$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(r^2-x^2)^{-1/2}.(0-2x)$$
$$=-x(r^2-x^2)^{-1/2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have to* use the Chain Rule, in fact you barely have to use calculus at all. For the curve $y=(r^2-x^2)^{1/2}$ is the top half of the circle with centre the origin and radius $r$.

It is well-known from geometry that the tangent line to the circle at the point $P=(x,(r^2-x^2)^{1/2})$ is perpendicular to the line joining the origin to $P$.

That line has slope $\frac{(r^2-x^2)^{1/2}}{x}$, so the tangent line has slope the negative of the reciprocal of this, namely $\frac{-x}{(r^2-x^2)^{1/2}}$.

If you choose not to use the geometry, you can still avoid the Chain Rule by finding the derivative using the *definition* of the derivative. But this is substantially more messy than using the Chain Rule.